# I'm trying to implement 2 factor authentication on the cheap. How would I do that?

Tags: security, authentication

Ok so I need 2 of the 3.

Something the user knows.
Something the user has.
Something the user is.

I have a system that is exposed to the internet and we need clients to connect in a secure manner to satisfy our security standards.

I'm thinking when a user registers to use our system we send them an application that they install on their home system. The application generates a key based on a timed randomness algorithm. Our application server has the same algorithm so when the user submits their credentials with the key we know that they are a legitimate user.

Is this a valid method of 2 factor authentication?

What is another way of doing this?

Are there any pitfalls that I should be aware of?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: humor: something the user is: dumb enough to trust sensitive stuff to on-the-cheap security.

Comment: If this is mission critical, or if breakage would cost your clients a monetary loss, one thing you'll need is very, very good insurance.

Comment: Cheap does not mean insecure. I think it is prudent to think of a way around a $50 a head FOB. Hmm, perhaps we should just mail our users a KEY.

Comment: 'Inexpensively,' 'economically' or 'efficiently' imply prudence to me; 'on the cheap' seems to imply a lack of concern for the consequences, or a lack of forethought. My apologies for any offence, but my advice still stands: you need good insurance. The reason security is typically expensive seems to be because the security contractor, or their insurer, bears -at least *part* of- the cost of errors in implementation. If you roll your own, then you need to be able to bear that cost.

Comment: Thanks for your concern ricebowl :)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys! Looks like I should shop around a little more before I go out and try to implement my own solution. :D

Comment: Note that you might want to also ask this (or a closely related) question over at ServerFault. The folks there will have a different point of view, and are likely to have real world experience with how various approaches fare across real user communities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid method of performing two-factor authentication. The token security (the program on the computer) is of course only as safe as the computer is. If its running Windows, all bets are off.

You can also go to RSA or other vendors and license their SecurID (or other brand) tokens, as well as the necessary middleware. Its a validated solution, and at the very least there is someone else to blame.

For time based systems, there is usually an allowed "window" where the token is valid (more than the roll-over point) to allow for time skew. You can also check with an NTP server (using SNTP, simple to implement) to get accurate time information.

As with all security systems, there are numerous pitfalls. They are very hard to get right. Be warned. Buy insurance ;)

Answer (score 3):

A grid-card system it's a also a cheap two way authentication schema.

[image]

You can generate a Grid Card using random numbers or letters and store the values on the server. Then you give a card to every user and store the card serial number. Later, at login time, you ask for the token in a row and column and then check the value on the server.

Comment: Clever indeed, but not all that secure either. One could get access to that card and photocopy it or take a quick picture of it using a smartphone. Vigilience of the end-user is a key factor.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use X.509 client certificates? They're free.

Comment: The maintenance around this infrastructure can be quite painful which... in the end, is not really free. I get your point, although having done it, I would not recommend it as a cheap solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a phone verification solutions to take the authentication off the internet?  This proves a more reliable authentication.  I heard a company Telesign does stuff with that, like blocking VOIP numbers.  You should check them out and its pretty inexpensive.

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" with the app on the computer, is that it's not something that someone has. It's something "anyone" can have. That app can (potentially) be installed, and reinstalled, and copied, all over the place. Pretty soon the home computer "has" it, the office computer "has" it, the laptop -- the one they just lost, that is -- has it, etc.

So, it's not a singular thing. Same goes with an issued certificate.

Not saying it's totally ineffective, but just that it's not unique, and that can be a potential issue.

A popular "cheap" technique is an SMS message to a cell phone. The person logs in, then the computer sends out an SMS code with, say, 6 digits, to the registered phone number, and then that number needs to be typed in. Obviously, there are issues with this. Not everyone has a cell phone, many are charge for SMS messages, etc. But it can work well in some environments.

Similarly, Voice Response systems can call a user on their phone and "read" the code to them. This can incur phone charges for the company of course.

Answer (score 2):

There is always the option of replacing the expensive key fob with paper containing a list of single-use passcodes. You would still need to roll your own backend to match the passcode generation algorithm (don't forget to provide an easy way for the user to resynchronize when he forgot to cross the last one off, or crossed off one too many), as well as the administrative task of getting the user to collect more paper before a user is stranded in the field without any passcodes left to use.

One example of this is Steve Gibson's [Perfect Paper Password](https://www.grc.com/ppp.htm) system. He's made the specs and algorithms open, and provides a closed-source implementation of his own. Others have built open source implementations. His system may in fact not be perfect, but it is an interesting idea for one way to approach the problem.

Regardless of what system you choose to implement, it will still be worth spending a little money on a review by a security expert...

Answer (score 1):

Why not assign them a certificate in addition to a login / password.